# Return whole array from zonal stats

Tags: geopandas, zonal-statistics

There are some good examples of how to calculate zonal stats using geopandas and Rasterio/GDAL but all of these return a single statistic. Is there a method to return all of the pixel values so that custom statistics can be performed on the array of returned values?

so instead of:

```
gdf['mean'] = pd.DataFrame(
    zonal_stats(
    vectors=gdf['geometry'], 
    raster='raster.tif', 
    stats='mean'
    )
)['mean']
```

you would have something like:

```
gdf['All'] = pd.DataFrame(
        zonal_stats(
        vectors=gdf['geometry'], 
        raster='raster.tif', 
        stats='array'
    )
)['array']
```

This was originally closed as it was categorized as being answered elsewhere but the answer provided wasn't suitable ([Geopandas and Zonal Statistic error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177035/geopandas-and-zonal-statistic-error)). This answer does not demonstrate how to get the array.

Comment: You can define your own stats: https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#user-defined-statistics. Is this what you are after? Also, when you read a raster using Rasterio, you are generating a DatasetReader, which you can use to access a Numpy ndarray. From there you can calculate any summary statistics you need. More details: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading.html#reading-datasets

Comment: @Aaron rather than the custom statistic, I'd really just like to have the array, but maybe I can achieve that by not defining a function? Otherwise I may have to look into windowed reads or something. Basically I need the pixels to pass into the next step of the workflow, rather than a single stat (e.g. mean)

Comment: How about reading the raster as a Numpy ndarray?

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, I think I will have to read the raster as a numpy array, but doing a windowed read using the polygon as the bbox

Answer (score 2):

If anyone needs the whole array their zonal stats are based on, I did this:

```
def my_arr(x):
    return x

def main():

    stats = zonal_stats(file,image,stats="count",add_stats={'my_arr':my_arr}, geojson_out=True)

    data = np.ma.getdata(stats[0]['properties']['my_arr'])
    mask = np.ma.getmask(stats[0]['properties']['my_arr'])

    # Get only pixel centroids
    Arr = data[mask==False]
```