# Find mean zonal stats using a geoseries or GeoJSON object - Python

Tags: python, geometry, zonal-statistics, rasterstats

I have a TIFF file with imperviousness levels and a Geoseries object containing the boundary coordinates of circles around 9 points. I want to find the mean value using zonal_stats but I don't know how to pass the circle geometry objects.

```
geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]
geodata=gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
buf_df = gpd.GeoSeries(geometry)
buff_circle= buf_df.buffer(0.001, cap_style = 1)
```

The buff_circle has the boundary coordinates of the circles

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421774/2856

Comment: I don't have my polygon in a shapefile. Just this geoseries variable 'buff_circle' How do I save my circle polygon in a shapefile?

Comment: The answer linked to uses geopandas geoseries just like you, shapefile is irrelevant.

Comment: When I pass my Geoseries object "buff_circle" I get this warning 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rasterstats/io.py:313: UserWarning: Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly
  warnings.warn("Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly")
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rasterstats/io.py:313: UserWarning: Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly
  warnings.warn("Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly")

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following that buffers, runs zonal stats and joins back to the original `df` ought to work. Obviously you'll need to fill out the `df` creation etc.

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

your_raster = "/path/to/raster"
df = ...?
crs = ...?

geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]
buf_df = gpd.GeoSeries(geometry)
buff_circle= buf_df.buffer(0.001, cap_style = 1)

# zonal stats
stats = zonal_stats(buff_circle, your_raster, stats="mean")

# Join stats to gdf 
sdf = pd.DataFrame(stats)
sdf = pd.concat([df, sdf], axis=1)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=buff_circle)
```

Comment: `from rasterstats import zonal_stats, point_query
rf = '/content/drive/MyDrive/GIS/Coding_task/imperviousness_raster_data/NLCD_2016_Impervious_L48_20190405_aeCiajHeNAvXB2754sYm.tiff'
rds = rasterio.open(rf)
stats = zonal_stats(buff_circle, rds, stats="mean")
sdf = pd.DataFrame(stats)`

I get this error while executing the stats = .... line


AttributeError: '_GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'transform'

Comment: @KarthikEswar edit your question to include this error and the output of either `gdalinfo NLCD_2016_Impervious_L48_20190405_aeCiajHeNAvXB2754sYm.tiff` or `rio info NLCD_2016_Impervious_L48_20190405_aeCiajHeNAvXB2754sYm.tiff`